# How to pass Addon items on buttonclick in customcell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with variable number of cells representing addon items. They are custom cells with a checkbox button which triggered to new ViewController.

How can I pass the Addon items which is displayed in cell on triggered the button?

I have tried to pass the cell number using tag property from the button but what about the  data passing on button click.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("itemCell")as! ItemTableViewCell

    cell.itemName.text = (items?[indexPath.row] as? [String:AnyObject])?["name"] as? String

    cell.itemPrice!.text = "£\((items?[indexPath.row] as? [String:AnyObject])?["price"] as! String)"

    itemAddon = (items![indexPath.row] as! [String:AnyObject])["addon"] as? String


    cell.orderBtnOutlet.tag = indexPath.row


    return cell
}
```

I have to pass itemname, itemPrice, and itemaddon to ItemTableViewCell based on its button click on each cell. How can I pass??

Comment: have a look at this http://blog.xebia.com/understanding-the-sender-in-segues-and-use-it-to-pass-on-data-to-another-view-controller/

Comment: My button is on customcell nib view not on view controller@UlliH  .. and there is no segue here . I have to pass data to its custom cell.

Comment: how do u select the cell? With tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ?

Comment: I made the cell selection property as none..  according to the  project requirement from storyboard.so i dont think so it will work@UlliH

Comment: I also have tried this one.. when i click on the cell it works but when on button which is on custom cell its not working..@UlliH

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to button in your presented vc, you can access cell by `let cell = button.superview as! ItemTableViewCell`
Then you can access cell labels text. 
But it is not good approach. 
If you assigned button action in storyboard to present anothet virw controller, it anyway has segue. Assign it an identifier and in your tableviewcontroller override method `prepareForSegue`, where you can assign needed properies of targetVC